# ViewModel getSingle(id) returns null and causes Logcat to return error

Tags: android, kotlin, repository, android-room, android-viewmodel

I have an App using latest dependencies and Gradle 8.3 with Kotlin DSL. The ViewModel is working fine to retrieve all data from the Room local SQLite Database. But doesn't work for retrieving single Recipe by id. The App compiles without errors. Issue found using Logcat.

Here is the code of different Kotlin files associated with this project.

**RecipeDatabase.kt**

```
@Database(
entities = [RecipeModel::class],
version = Constants.version,
exportSchema = false
)
abstract class RecipeDatabase: RoomDatabase() {

    abstract fun recipeDao(): RecipeDAO

    companion object{

        @Volatile
        private var INSTANCE: RecipeDatabase? = null

        fun getDatabase(
            context: Context
        ): RecipeDatabase{
            val tempInstance = INSTANCE
            if(tempInstance != null){
                return tempInstance
            }
            synchronized(this) {
                val instance = Room.databaseBuilder(context, RecipeDatabase::class.java, Constants.database)
                    .createFromAsset(Constants.databaseLocation)
                    .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                    .build()
                INSTANCE = instance
                return instance
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**RecipeDAO.kt**

```
@Dao
interface RecipeDAO {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM recipes ORDER BY id ASC")
    fun readAllData(): LiveData<List<RecipeModel>> // THIS WORKS

    @Query("SELECT * FROM recipes WHERE id=:id")
    fun loadSingle(id: String): LiveData<RecipeModel> // THIS DOESNT

}
```

**RecipeRepository.kt**

```
class RecipeRepository(private val recipeDAO: RecipeDAO) {

val readAllData: LiveData<List<RecipeModel>> = recipeDAO.readAllData() // THIS WORKS

fun loadSingle(recipeId: String): LiveData<RecipeModel> {
    return recipeDAO.loadSingle(recipeId)
}

}
```

**RecipeViewModel**

```
 class RecipeViewModel(application: Application): AndroidViewModel(application) {

    val readAllData: LiveData<List<RecipeModel>>
    private val repository: RecipeRepository
    lateinit var eventSingle: LiveData<RecipeModel>

    init {
        val recipeDAO = RecipeDatabase.getDatabase(application).recipeDao()
        repository = RecipeRepository(recipeDAO)
        readAllData = repository.readAllData // THIS WORKS
    }

    fun getSingle(recipeId: String) { // THIS DOESNT
        eventSingle = repository.loadSingle(recipeId)
    }

}
```

**Composable RecipeScreen.kt**

```
@Composable
fun RecipeScreen(navController: NavHostController, recipeViewModel: RecipeViewModel, recipeID: Int) {
    println("RECIPE ID" + recipeID.toString()) // THIS WORKS
    val recipeAvailable = recipeViewModel.getSingle(recipeID.toString()) // THIS DOESNT
    val available by recipeViewModel.eventSingle.observeAsState() // THIS DOESNT
    println(available) // <-- null
}
```

**NavHost composable**

```
composable(route = Recipe.route) {
            backStackEntry ->
        val recipeID = backStackEntry.arguments?.getString("recipeID")
        if (recipeID != "") {
            RecipeScreen(navController, recipeViewModel, recipeID!!.toInt())
        }
    }
```

The problem was caused by this code (how can I replace the Image composable so it waits even if it has drawable set to null at first?) :

```
@Composable
fun Hero(recipePreview: RecipeModel) {
val context = LocalContext.current
val imageName = recipePreview.image.replace(".jpg", "")
val drawableId = remember(imageName) {
    context.resources.getIdentifier(
        imageName,
        "drawable",
        context.packageName
    )
}
Box(Modifier.height(280.dp)) {
    Image(
        painter = painterResource(id = drawableId),
        contentDescription = recipePreview.title,
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .fillMaxHeight(),
        contentScale = ContentScale.FillBounds,
    )
}
}
```

When I remove Image the rest of the Recipe appears. So only the Image is the problem, because at first I have null.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might not be the only issue, but combining `var` with LiveData is going to cause problems. The UI layer begins observing the first LiveData. When you change the property to point at a different LiveData, the UI layer doesn't know and just keeps observing the first LiveData.

To solve this, you can create a backing LiveData of the requested IDs, and [`switchMap`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/lifecycle/package-summary#(androidx.lifecycle.LiveData).switchMap(kotlin.Function1)) to produce the final map of single database rows that you want.

Updated ViewModel code:

```
class RecipeViewModel(application: Application): AndroidViewModel(application) {

    val readAllData: LiveData<List<RecipeModel>>
    private val repository: RecipeRepository
    private val eventSingleId = MutableLiveData<String>()
    val eventSingle: LiveData<RecipeModel> =
        eventSingleId.switchMap { repository.loadSingle(it) }

    init {
        val recipeDAO = RecipeDatabase.getDatabase(application).recipeDao()
        repository = RecipeRepository(recipeDAO)
        readAllData = repository.readAllData
    }

    fun getSingle(recipeId: String) {
        eventSingleId.value = recipeId
    }

}
```

By the way, your singleton access of the database is vulnerable to instantiating two databases. It needs to be a double-checked lock. Update your code to do a second check for it having been instantiated inside the synchronized block:

```
fun getDatabase(
    context: Context
): RecipeDatabase{
    var instance = INSTANCE
    if(instance != null){
        return tempInstance
    }
    synchronized(this) {
        instance = INSTANCE
        if(instance != null){
            return instance
        }
        instance = Room.databaseBuilder(context, RecipeDatabase::class.java, Constants.database)
            .createFromAsset(Constants.databaseLocation)
            .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
            .build()
        INSTANCE = instance
        return instance
    }
}
```

Or to simplify the code using Elvis operators and `also`:

```
fun getDatabase(
    context: Context
): RecipeDatabase =
    INSTANCE ?: synchronized(this) {
        INSTANCE ?: Room.databaseBuilder(context, RecipeDatabase::class.java, Constants.database)
            .createFromAsset(Constants.databaseLocation)
            .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
            .build()
            .also { INSTANCE = it }
    }
```

Comment: First thank you for answering, I made the changes using the second getDatabase and changed the ViewModel accordingly but still getting same Null.

Comment: I added the code of the Image composable causing the app to crash after ViewModel set to null for only few milliseconds then it has the data. Please how can I replace the Image composable so it waits?

Comment: Oh, yes, I didn't catch that. If you print the result immediately you get null (the default starting value) because it hasn't had a chance to actually retrieve the item yet, since that happens asynchronously. You basically need to use `if (available != null)` / `else`, and in the `else` block is where you put whatever you want the Composable to show before the data arrives. Could be a progress bar, or in this case you probably just want to omit the else branch to leave the screen blank since retrieving a single row from the database will be very fast.